# Trying to find and replace general expressions within my text

Tags: python, regex, string

Here is a sample text:

> initiated to address the deviation to SOP-020583v11.0 Section
>   SOP-016248v2.0 john doe, john doe SOP-020583 fake text, this is all
>   fake.

I have hundreds of passages just like this:

> initiated to address the deviation to acafjd Section abgcej john doe,
>   john doe  fake text, this is all fake

I created the following function to find unique SOP numbers:

```
def regex_list(regex,input_doc):
    result = re.compile(regex)
    regex_list = [result.findall(x) for x in input_doc]
    final_regex_list = [x for l in regex_list for x in l]
    final_regex_list = list(set(final_regex_list))
    return final_regex_list
```

I'd like to take it a step further and replace it as I'm finding the SOP numbers. So after it has run through this function it would like this:

I want to replace it with some text representation of the number. I'm thinking of using the character that is associated with that number.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `re.sub`.

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> ...If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub